# What is the correct way to post images on django-rest-framework server using javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a POST API view that accepts an image and a style sting and returns a styled image.
It works on postman just fine but I cannot get it to work using fetch API.

Serializer:

```
class GetImageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField()
    style = serializers.CharField()
```

DRF view:

```
class PostImage(APIView):
    serializer_class = GetImageSerializer
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]
    
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(request.data) # Debug
        img = request.data.get('image')
        # Process
        response = FileResponse(img)
        return response
```

The fetch call:

```
json = {}
json["image"] = this.state.image
json["style"] = "models\\wave\\wave200.pth"
console.log("sending --- ", json) //debug

fetch('/style_transfer/style/',
    {
        headers: { "Content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" },
        body: json,
        method: "POST"
    }
).then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        console.log("couldn't fetch image")
    }
    return response.json()
})
.then(data => {
    console.log("fetched data")
    console.log(data)
```

outputs of console logs. This shows that the correct data is in json dictionary
[image]
But the data isn't received by DRF server.
The `print(request.data)` from the view returns `<QueryDict: {}>`.
The strange part is that the same code works with postman.

### Things I've tried:

- Remove the `headers` from fetch request - This throws unsupported media type error
- Set content-type to `"application/json"` - This reads the string parameter but image key is empty. this is what `request.data` looks like `{'image': {}, 'style': 'models\\wave\\wave200.pth'}`

I want to understand what's causing this issue. I've read several similar threads but I couldn't find the recommended way to do something like this. So, what's the issue and what is the recommended way of doing this?