# How to post an image on Django Rest server using fetch API?

Tags: javascript, python, django, fetch-api

I have a Django Rest Framework view that accepts an image and a style sting:

```
class PostImage(APIView):
    serializer_class = GetImageSerializer
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(request.data) # debug
        img = request.data.get('image')
        ...
        response = FileResponse(img)
        return response
```

I get the correct output using Postman. Here's the curl command that it executes:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/style_transfer/style/' \
--form 'image=@"/C:/User/949690-kg.jpg"' \
--form 'style
="models\\\\tokyo_ghoul\\\\tokyo_ghoul_aggressive.pth"'
```

Here's the javascript snippet generated by postman for the same task. I've added `content-type` because it is required by DRF.

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("image", fileInput.files[0], "/C:/Users/949690-kg.jpg");
formdata.append("style\n", "models\\\\tokyo_ghoul\\\\tokyo_ghoul_aggressive.pth");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formdata,
  redirect: 'follow',
  headers: { "Content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" }

};

fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/style_transfer/style/", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

On executing the above snippet on postman, I get the following error:

```
{
    "detail": "Unsupported media type \"application/javascript\" in request."
}
```

The strange part is that the curl command generated by postman work as expected. I have also asked this question a few days back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68604487/what-is-the-correct-way-to-post-images-on-django-rest-framework-server-using-jav), and it has some more context. Why does this happen and how to fix this?

Comment: Can you tried `"Content-Type": "application/json"`? DRF is a json API. But I think the best option for it, is to convert to base64 the image

Comment: @DiegoPeñalverMontero Yes I've tried `"Content-Type": "application/json"` but it didn't work. Can you tell me how I can modify the above snippet to convert the image to base64? I've limited experience in js, as I don't use it in my daily work. Thanks for helping!